# Any one was integrating the Data Tabes jquery plugin with Zend Framework?

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatable, zend-db-table

I was wondered is any one was integrating the DataTabes jquery  plugin with Zend Framework?
I mean I did basic serverside processing but will be good to have a full server-side processing integration with Zend_DB_Tables.

thanks Arman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try : [zf-datatables](https://github.com/jamesj2/zf-datatables).

It's works for what I need it for.